# Spring boot - unused properties in aplication.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

Do you know why IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.02.1 does not see properties in aplication.properties? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdmAa.png)
Does the compiler recognize and use them even though it cannot see them?
If you need more information about this problem ask me I will write back as soon as possible.

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: It is the community edition it doesn't have build in support for Spring, Spring Boot etc. you need the Ultimate edition for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Spring & Spring Boot assistance](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-boot.html) comes with [IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/intellij-frameworks/) which can detect all your Beans (along with its usages and injections), Rest Controller Endpoints, Application Properties (along with the classes that use those properties), Spring relevant auto completions, etc. The said features are not available in [IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) which is why you see those application properties as unused. Still, in reality, it is being used and your application should pick them up just fine (assuming you've set up things correctly).

These missing features however should not stop you from developing Spring Boot (or any JVM frameworks for that matter) applications using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.

Answer (score 0):

As the application.properties was not in a source folder, with the name src/main/resource maybe that's it